# TimePickerDialog: Change hours/minutes text size

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-timepicker

I want to change the font of time as below to 42sp. Is `TimePickerDialog` possible to change the font size?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`TimePickerDialog` is **not** designed in a way, that would allow clients to change the font size. Thus, it's strongly discouraged to do so.

Still, if for some specific reason you need to do so, you are able to stick with following tricky and non-reliable way:

```
      val mTimePickerField = TimePickerDialog::class.java.getDeclaredField("mTimePicker")
      mTimePickerField.isAccessible = true

      val mTimePicker = mTimePickerField.get(timePickerDialog) as TimePicker
      val hours: TextView? = mTimePicker.findViewById(resources.getIdentifier("android:id/hours", "id", packageName))
      val separator: TextView? = mTimePicker.findViewById(resources.getIdentifier("android:id/separator", "id", packageName))
      val minutes: TextView? = mTimePicker.findViewById(resources.getIdentifier("android:id/minutes", "id", packageName))

      hours?.textSize = 12f
      separator?.textSize = 12f
      minutes?.textSize = 12f
```

Here's what you'll get:

[image]

[`time_picker_header_material.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/time_picker_header_material.xml) is the actual header layout that `TimePickerDialog` will inflate, thus you can enhance am/pm fields as per your needs with the same approach as it's done for hours/separator/minute.

Comment: I have ideal on your code given....but im using java, so i dont know how to change the code to java. Hope you can teach me with java

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar kind of issues you were facing. I finally used this GitHub [library](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#using-material-datetime-pickers) to customise the text sizes. [Issue 1](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/issues/327) and [Issue 2](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/issues/189) of that library could point you on how to increase text sizes. The code is in Java

Answer (score 0):

By default time picker has its own style but if you define other custom textview Style, then header of timepicker will be affected.so To Resolve this, you have to give custom style as follow

open your style or theme.xml file

inside style tag add following item

```
        <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/customTimePickerDialogTheme</item>
```

then add the following style outside the default style tag (inside resources)

```
  <style name="customTimePickerDialogTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:headerBackground">#ff80cbc4</item>
    </style>
```

By this way we achieve our default custom timepicker design.Now you can change font, texsize,color using other attribute inside customTimePickerDialogTheme.